# GPS Tracking app in iOS

Tags: mobile, geolocation, gps

I have a project in mind where I could track a vehicle using a tracking device on my iPhone. I need a suitable device to work with. I'd really appreciate it if someone could suggest me an appropriate tracking device to use and suggest ways to extract that tracking info.

Comment: What do you mean by "tracking device"> An iPhone has a GPS built into it. You can access the GPS data using `CLLocationManager` and associated classes.

Comment: As the comment above mentions, why did you flag this ios?  If your looking for a device that can keep track of its location over time, There are tons on the web https://www.google.com/search?q=gps+tracker  What does this have to do with ios?

Comment: i wanna get the latitude/longitude info from the tracking device and use it on my iphone to show where the vehicle is. Cant put a phone on a vehicle right.

Comment: This question isn't suitable for SO.  It is meant for questions like "I tried this code, why doesn't it work".   Not for questions like "Can you suggest ....?"

Comment: Welcome.  But you should read the FAQ -> http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Consider upvoting all usefull answers, and accept the best one.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to find tracking hardware that interfaces with iPhone. Perhaps you should look in the iTunes app store for apps that already integrate with external GPS hardware, for example [Tagg](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tagg-the-pet-tracker/id474539050?mt=8) or [Spotlight](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spotlight-gps-pet-locator/id351109362?mt=8) (I have no affiliation with these products). That's a pet tracking solution, but something like that might be more like what you need, namely an app that already is integrated with an external tracking device.

---

This answer assumed the OP was trying to get the location of the iPhone. Turns out that he wanted the location of an external GPS tracking device. Thus, this answer is not applicable.

Original answer:

See Apple's [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) which should walk you through what you need if you want to do this with your iPhone (which I presume from your posting it here with the `iOS` tag).

This has a nice introduction on how to [determine the user's location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW9), and a section on [how to get this information in the background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10).

You really should go through that guide, go through some of the examples, and you should be well on your way.

Comment: Thank you. I basically wanna do what ups does. provide the location info of the package on my iphone. I know they use a device for tracking the location of the vehicle. I wanna use a similar kind of device, get the latitude/longitude info from it and show it on my iPhone. DO you have any suggestions?

Comment: @user1863944 Look at my updated answer which directs you to the appropriate programming topics. If you're looking for an app that does this, there are plenty in the iTunes store. I've used `Trails` (which I have no affiliation with) for tracking my location (which I then marry with my photographs to do geotagging). There have to be tons of existing apps that do this.

Comment: @Rob .. the OP is looking for a device that sends its location data in real time and is then displayed on the users phone.  Not the users location.

Comment: i dont wanna track my location. I wanna put a device in vehicle and track that vehicle. I cant put a phone on a vehicle right? so i need some kind of a tracking device to work with. use that device's latitude/longitude info on my iphone to track that vehicle.

Comment: @peter M yes, you are right. do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: @ShriramVenkataraman Sorry, I misunderstood the question. As others have said, you really need to find a device that does the GPS tracking and look for ones that provide an API that you can interface with. Sorry, I don't know of specific devices. I googled "gps tracking units api" and got a few hits, though. You'll just have to dig around and find something. Look for ones that provide a web-based API (maybe XML/JSON interfaces).

Comment: @ShriramVenkataraman the best place to answer this question is search google for GPS trackers

Comment: thanks guys. i figured that I need a device that has a web API but was just wondering which device could be ideal/effective/cheap.

Comment: @ShriramVenkataraman Perhaps you can search the iTunes store for existing apps that communicate with external GPS tracking solutions. Perhaps [Tagg](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tagg-the-pet-tracker/id474539050?mt=8). That's designed for tracking pets, but it's functionally close to what you're asking about.

Comment: i found out one called OpenGTS. It's a open source system being used in several countries supposedly.

Comment: Tagg is a great example, Rob. I'll look into it. I have to write server side code anyway irrespective of the device I choose.

Answer (score 0):

A company named "Falcom" sells such devices. However you have to write server side Software to communicate with that devices, which use a proprietary protcoll.
But do not underestimate such a project.

Comment: yep. it is good example. I found one called openGTS. Gotta write server side code anyway.